# GTK Python gtk.TextBuffer(table=None) constructor error

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk

I'm porting a Python GTK application from python2 to python3, using version `3.5.2`.  As part of this, I'm switching to updated `GTK` API calls.  I need to call the `gtk.TextBuffer` constructor, described [here][1].  Following that documentation, I wrote:

`tb = gtk.TextBuffer(table=text_tag_table)`

This gives the following error:

`` *** TypeError: gobject `GtkTextBuffer' doesn't support property 'table' ``

I tried removing the `table=` part of the call:

`gtk.TextBuffer(table=text_tag_table)`

This gives:

`*** TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)`

I can call the constructor without arguments, e.g., `tb = gtk.TextBuffer()`.  I tried setting the tag table manually, like this:

`tb.set_property("tag-table", text_tag_table)`

This gives a warning:

`__main__:1: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "tag-table" for object 'GtkTextBuffer' can't be set after construction`

It seems like the original constructor with the `table=` arg should work.  Can anyone help me figure out why it throws a `TypeError`?  I did confirm using `pydb` that `text_tag_table` is an object of the correct type:

```
(Pdb) p text_tag_table
<Gtk.TextTagTable object at 0x7fb723d6b288 (GtkTextTagTable at 0x2b2e8e0)>
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The fix for this was to use the `new` method:

`tb = gtk.TextBuffer.new(table=text_tag_table)`

I'm a bit surprised that this works, but it seems fine!